# Access2010 to PowerPoint2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, powerpoint, ms-access-2007

I have a VBA program in Access able to write to shapes in an already existing PPT.  It also will make copies of slides and insert/paste them as well.

However, when I write to the shape the shape will then change size - does not maintain its original shape.  Let's say the shape could contain 5 lines, it comes down to one line if that is all that is being written.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Set the shape's .TextFrame.AutoSize property to ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText to make the shape resize to accommodate the text within it or set it to ppAutoSizeNone to force the shape to stay the same size, however much text it contains.